# Render multiple queries to the same jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, orientdb, orientjs

Client asks for dynamic information that will be served into 2 tables or lists in the same webpage. Lets say for example, to compare between 2 objects or articles.

JADE TEMPLATE

```
extends layout.jade

block content1
    div= foo_table
block content2
    div= bar_table
```

DATABASE QUERY

```
var table1 = db.query('select * from table where ...')
    .then(function (result){
        console.log(result);
    });

var table2 = db.query('select * from table where ...')
    .then(function (result){
        console.log(result);
    });

//I DON'T WANT TO SEND TO CONSOLE, JUST GET THE DATA, BUT IT IS ASYNCHRONOUS
```

Using **return** instead of **console.log** does not return the set of data.

```
.then(function (result){
        return(result);
    });

No variable defined inside then() is persistent.
```

ROUTER CODE

If I use this method it works, but...:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    db.query('select * from table where ...')
    .then(function (result){
            res.send(result);
        });
```

The problem is that it only can serve 1 query.

I want to serve 2 blocks simultaneously:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('./index', { foo_table: table1, bar_table: table2});
};
```

- The only think I get is the **console.log** but there's no way to
  pass the result of the query to the template (**var tables** do not
  store the result of the query).
- Any variable that I create inside a "then" or async function is not
  persistent.
- JSON.stringify or parse do not convert the result of these nested functions.
- Calling back functions or creating functions after template variable
  definitions (footable: *, bartable: *) does not work.
- As the queries are thenable I cannot find any way to convert into
  storable, or instead, collect results from various thenable queries
  to serve the final info and render the template variables.
- Do I have to create a separate AJAX method for each table when the
  page is loaded?
- I want to serve the whole page with the get method from begining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using (or the libraries you use are based on) something like [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise) (or any other promise library) then you should be able to do it like this:

```
Promise.all([
    db.query('select * from foo where ...'),
    db.query('select * from bar where ...')
])
.spread(function(foo, bar) {
    /* prepare data as you need them */
    res.render('./index', { foo_table: foo, bar_table: bar});
});
```

`Promise.all` asynchronously "waits" until both methods (the db queries) in the passed array have finished and returned, and then passes both results together to the callback passed to `.spread()` (like in [this](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#spreadfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise) example).

Comment: Wow, thanks, very much :) The only thing I had to change is that for an unknown reason the results from both queries are stored in foo, and bar remains undefined. I had to separate foo[0] and foo[1] to get the 2 responses.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I mixed it up a bit. You have to either use `.then` and parse the array yourself, like you already mentioned, or you can use `.spread` instead, which will flatten the array to single parameters like my original intention was. I changed `.then` to `.spread` in the answer. Thanks for feedback :)